# Meaning of "встал колом"

Tags: словоупотребление

In this passage, I'm wondering if **встал колом** is correct (I didn't write this - it was written by a native Russian speaker on a forum for anecdotes), and if so, what is the literal interpretation word for word?

> Рассказал сегодня знакомый, далее от первого лица. Купили себе в офис
>   шредер. Небольшой, максимально 6 листов за раз жуёт, но нам больше и
>   не нужно. Объяснил, что к чему всем. Десять раз повторил что 6 листов
>   максимум. Сижу работаю. К шредеру подходит Ира (имя изменено), берет 6
>   листов, сворачивает пополам и суёт в шредер. Тот **встал колом**, не
>   работает, завтра в ремонт повезу.

Comment: "Stopped/stuck dead" is a good  translation if you need an idiomatic expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When something is completely stuck, most likely in a perpendicular position - it's "встать колом".

Examples of usage:

- Проспект Гагарина встал колом из-за ДТП. (There's a trafic jam on Gagarina Avenue because of an accident).
- В Химках из-за взрыва водопроводных труб асфальт встал колом. (There's a hump in the asphalt following a water pipe explosion).

The other meaning is to harden:

- Из-за застывшей грязи плащ встал колом. (The coat became stiff with dirt).

Oh, and it's worth mentioning that we also use the phrase "стоять колом в горле" - when something is hard to swallow and it feels like it's stuck.

Comment: Thank you, Shahen! Is there any way you can translate your wonderful examples into English?

Comment: @CocoPop added some approximate translations.

Comment: Thank you ever so much. If it's helpful to you - I edited the translations and your comments to sound more natural))

Comment: If you'll allow a stupid question... in the text that I posted, is it the printer or the paper that's the subject of встал колом?

Comment: @CocoPop the shredder "встал колом" )

Comment: And is it ко́лом or коло́м?

Comment: @CocoPop кóлом (first vowel is stressed)

Answer (score 2):

I am not a native speaker and encountered this Russian expression only once, in a very different context: a man's physiological reaction to a sexually attractive woman...

Comment: Well after Shabunc's explanation, that would make perfect sense! 

Comment: I, as native speaker, never heard that someone use "Встать колом" in this meaning. While it is possible to use in this way, i don't think it's common. But maybe it depends on area and people you're talking to

Comment: Also a native speaker, never heard anyone use it this way.

Comment: This looks like a joke. I never encountered this as a native speaker. It makes a funny impression of being literally OK but the idiom means stuck, broke, so it somehow makes a contrast between idiomatic and literal meaning.